# rEFInd lists extra boot options and trying to remove them isn't working

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, uefi

I just got Ubuntu 14.04 to dual-boot with Windows 8.1 (it was quite the process). Anyway, I wanted to use burg instead of grub2 as the boot loader, but that wouldn't work with UEFI, so I am trying to get rEFInd set up now instead. It currently will boot with all the additional linux options (i.e. grubx64.efi, vmlinuz...). The solution I was trying to follow didn't affect anything at all, so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Solution: Edit the file "refind.conf" and add "grubx64.efi" to the end of the line "dont_scan_files".

I've tried changing it so it looked like
`#dont_scan_files shim.efi,MokManager.efi,grubx64.efi` (shim and mokmanager were already there).
And I've tried simply adding the line `#dont_scan_files + grubx86.efi` because the sample thing said to include a + first. But still no change. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I prefer Grub2 over having a cluttered rEFInd.

Edit: Btw https://askubuntu.com/questions/630258/refind-question-remove-multiple-boot-items is the best explanation I've found, but I'm still not understanding how to "add the efi file to 'dont_scan_files'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the instructions and your config differ by a `#` sign. In many configuration file formats, it indicates a comment line – entirely ignored by the program itself. (You say "shim and mokmanager were already there", that's because the line was provided as an example.) Uncomment it by removing the `#` sign.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed to know. I didn't know why all the lines in these kind of files had the `#` sign in front and just assumed it meant the start of a new line or something. I got rid of the sign and it worked.